# Leaflet - Approach to avoid overlapping labels in javascript

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm creating a map using leaflet and javascript.
I've managed to add custom labels like this:
[image]

But when markers are too close, I obviously end up with a mess:

[image]

What I 've done so far is add conditions that doesn't display labels on small markers when the zoom is below a certain level. It helps a little.
But I'd like to find a more generic solution.

**What would be a good approach to detect if 2 circle markers are overlapping or too close to each other ?** (I'm using standard [CircleMarkers](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#circlemarker) so far)

I am a bit stuck on this.

Thanks for your help.

Mickael

Comment: This is a bit too open-ended. Usual approaches to this kind of problems include checking the distance of each pair of points (is the distance lower than the sum of their radii?) or going full-on on [r-tree](https://github.com/mourner/rbush) collisions if there's a lot of data (but that only checks for rectangular bboxes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I don't have too many markers, so what I did is compare a marker to all previous marker using

```
dist = map.latLngToLayerPoint(p1).distanceTo(map.latLngToLayerPoint(p2));
```

If the distance is inferior to the sum both radiuses, then I dont add a label.
But it needs to be recalculated when the zoom level changes.